# Clear the text of search menu in android

Tags: android, searchview

I have created a simple menu as follow, which contains a `Search View`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I have used `android:launchMode="singleTop"` method. Well after I perform a search and update UI, the text entered still remains there.

[image: image1]

What I want is after search button is pressed, the `Search View` should restore itself as:

[image]

Is there any way on how to shrink it back?

Answer (score 2):

Using what @Niti Misra initially suggested, I had to define `SearchView searchView = null;` at the top of my activity and use not inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` but inside `handleIntent`. Here is the full solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SearchView searchView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            myString = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
            searchView.setQuery("", false);
            searchView.clearFocus();

            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main key call that most people are missing in the other answers is `collapseActionView()` on the search menu item.

The calls to `setQuery`, `clearFocus`, etc. do clear out the view, but it continues to show until `collapseActionView`—which is really what most people want.

Here are the full steps (assuming you already have the XML menu items including the one with the actionViewClass as described in the standard SearchView Android documentation):

```
private SearchView mSearchView;

private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // inflate the action bar menu options, including the option that includes the search item (R.id.action_search)
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    // get the search menu item and target view
    mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); // the menu item with the appropriate actionViewClass setting
    mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();

    // setup the Android SearchManager to automatically send the appropriate search intents
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Regardless of what method you put the following code in, any time you are finished with the SearchView, use:

```
// anywhere you have a search item selected and are ready to close the search view...

// clear the search query in the toolbar so it is empty the next time the user
// opens the search view
mSearchView.setQuery("", false);  // 2nd argument is false so it doesn't re-submit a blank search query
// hide the SearchView action so the toolbar returns to normal mode showing the title and other menu items, etc.
mSearchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();
       if (mSearchView!=null && searchItem!=null) {
            mSearchView.clearFocus();
            searchItem.collapseActionView();
        }
```

As soon as you submit the query at the above code to close `actionView`

Comment: are you using ABS or stock `SearchView`

Comment: I am using Action Bar

Comment: you've suggestion enabled you've to do this in `OnSuggestionListener` also. and i edited the code please resuse.

Comment: where did you get `searchMenuItem` from?

Comment: Have you used `OnSuggestionListener` anywhere? It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setQuery("", false); // clear the text
searchView.setIconified(true); // close the search editor and make search icon again
```